# SQL SELECT with few nested JOINs

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have this relation , I need to write a query that with a given `@SellerId` will return a `CustomerFirstName`, `CustomerLastName` , `CustomerSSN` , `SellerComission` , `ProductName` and `ProductDescription`.

I got lost with `JOIN` syntax , the logic is find all customers records with **`SellerId = @SellerId`**
to JOIN it ON `UserId = CustomerId` with `FirstName,LastName` and `SSN` from  `Users` , then to JOIN ON `CustomerId` with all fields of `Sales` table and then to JOIN it with all fields `Products` table on `ProductId` . In other words I need a table of all sales of specific `Seller` that each record there will looks like:

`(SoldToFName,SoldToLastName,SoldToSSN,ProductName,ProductDescription,SellerComission)`

[image]

```
SELECT UserId, FirstName , LastName , SSN FROM Users JOIN Customers ON (Users.UserId = Customers.CustomerId) WHERE Customers.SellerId = @SellerId
```

this returns all the customers that connected to the seller .I dont know how to nest JOINs correctly

Comment: Please show what you have so far and we will help you to find mistakes if it has some.

Comment: Please share us what did you tried, what was the problem with it (error messages, etc). If you can please provide us some sample data and the desired output. (Or create an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com).) **If this is a homework , please try to solve it (especially if you want to work with databases in the future).**

Comment: @DimaRudaev, please put your sql query to the question, not to the comments.

Comment: Not a homework i finished my studies already , just forgot SQL syntax

Comment: What do you mean by nest joins? If you need data from another table add another join to your query. Hint, it would go after the current join and before the where clause.

Comment: Btw on my studies we concentrated on calculate queries I/O costs instead of write queries

Comment: First of all - thanks a lot !! Another question : I have in my requirement that I need to show in my page a sum off commissions , there is anyway to do it in this query or I need to write a new query that based on that one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Sean Lange for the hint about syntax

```
SELECT UserId, FirstName , LastName , SSN , Products.ProductId , Products.Name , Products.Description , Sales.SellerComission FROM Users 
    JOIN Customers ON (Users.UserId = Customers.CustomerId) 
    JOIN Sales ON (Customers.CustomerId=Sales.CustomerId)
    JOIN Products ON (Products.ProductId=Sales.ProductId)

    WHERE Customers.SellerId = @SellerId
```

Comment: Can I improve it somehow ??